# Dibujar en Canvas - NullPointerException

Tags: java, canvas

Estoy tratando de dibujar en **Canvas** por medio de la siguiente forma:

```
public void dibujar(){
    lapiz= canvas2.getGraphics();
    lapiz.setColor(Color.black);
    lapiz.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

Donde "lapiz" es de tipo `Graphics`, y canvas2 es de tipo `Canvas`. Aquí es donde creo el canvas:

```
    canvas2 = new Canvas();
    canvas2.setBounds(10, 10, (int)x, (int)y);
    contentPane.add(canvas2);
```

Aquí es donde muestro la ventana, lo que hago en el main, es crear un objeto que invoque el método iniciar():

```
public void iniciar() {
    dibujar();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

El problema es que me bota un **`NullPointerException`** en la línea donde le mando el color a "lápiz" y no entiendo por qué, se supone que ya inicialice el objeto, no sé si es por que no está tomando el contorno gráfico del canvas2 (así tengo entendido que funciona) o que.

Tengo entendido que lo mejor es crear una clase que hereda de Canvas (y así ya lo he utilizado y me ha servido), sin embargo estoy realizando unas pruebas, y quería saber si así se puede dibujar.

De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Al parecer el error comienza aqui: lapiz= canvas2.getGraphics();  como instanciaste lápiz? tal vez de se deba a que  no has asignado una nueva instancia a lápiz. muestra tu instancia de lápiz el erro va por ahí al parecer

Comment: Si se refiere a colocar lapiz= new Graphics(), no es posbile debido a que Graphics es una clase abstracta. Por otra parte, la excepcion me la bota en la linea lapiz.setColor();

Comment: Me refiero a el tipo de dato con el que inicializas "lapiz"  para que la instancia pueda funcionar.

Comment: No logro comprender, el tipo de dato, en el caso de getGraphics, devuelve el contexto para poder funcionar, ¿no?, con eso el lapiz ya debería tener como dibujar.

Comment: El problema es que `getGraphics()` está devolviendo nulo. Esto ocurre por que el gráfico aún no ha sido renderizado cuando lo intentas obtener. Inclusive no es recomentable hacerlo así. Una búsqueda rápida de "canvas.getGraphics() devuelve null" te daría opciones, pero todo lo que encuentro está en inglés. Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: SI, efectivamente primero toca desplegar la ventana para que obtenga el contexto gráfico, ahora el problema es que para que el dibujo se mantenga, toca estar dibujando constantemente, es decir, el método dibujar() tocó meterlo en un ciclo while, creo que estar dibujando lo mismo constantemente  no es correcto, pero no sé como mantener el dibujo sin estar dibujando constantemente